# Does Kirchhoff's law apply to displacement currents?

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetism

When dealing with AC or RF circuits, does one need to take into account the displacement currents (as derived from Maxwell's Laws or Heaviside's formulation) when applying Kirchhoff's law to a circuit analysis?

Why (or when) is this not normally done in circuit analysis tutorials?

Comment: You need to, and you do "take into account the displacement currents": otherwise, capacitors and microstrip stubs would participate in calculations as circuit breakers and not as useful reactive components.

Comment: Interesting.  It appears that most tutorials on A/C circuit analysis do not mention the term "displacement current" anywhere.  Maybe it's called something else?

Comment: So most circuit analysis tutorials do not mention displacement currents with respect to Kirchhoff's law because of their failure to clearly state that the textbook chapter only covers circuits consisting of lumped element approximations to reality?

Answer (score 3):

Displacement currents **inside** most circuits are limited to the space between capacitor plates (AFAIK). **Outside** circuits, the EM waves have changing electric field, so they too involve displacement current.

Kirchhoff's laws are based on the approximations / simplification made based on conservation of Energy (KVL) and conservation of charge (KCL) when applied to **lumped element** approximations of circuits.

[[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws)

> Kirchhoff's circuit laws are two equalities that deal with the current and potential difference (commonly known as voltage) in the lumped element model of electrical circuits.

In lumped parameter models, the capacitor is a lumped device, i.e., a *point* and so the gap between the plates are not modelled. They also do not deal with EM radiations (AFAIK). So both opportunities to use the concept of displacement current do not exist in those circuits which are modelled by lumped element models.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Kirchhoff's law apply to displacement currents?

Kirchhoff's Current Law is exact if and only if you include displacement currents, (or displacement currents are not present).

Kirchhoff's Current Law follows immediately from Heaviside's formulation of Ampere's Circuital Law with Maxwell's addition of a displacement current term.

$$\nabla \times \vec{B} = \mu_0(\vec{J} + \epsilon_0\frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial t})$$

where \$\vec{J}\$ is the conduction current density, and \$\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial t}\$ is the displacement current density.

Taking the divergence of both sides (and cancelling out \$\mu_0\$ gives Kirchhoff's Current Law in microscopic form.

$$0 = \nabla \cdot (\vec{J} + \epsilon_0\frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial t})$$

In macroscopic form, this says that in any closed region in space, not just in a circuit, and not just with "lumped elements", the sum of all conduction currents and displacement currents into (or out of) that region is exactly 0.

If Maxwell's equations hold, then Kirchhoff's Current Law (with displacement current) holds, without exception, and exactly.

Detailed Discussion of Kirchhoff's law and displacement current point and its implications are found in:

1. Eisenberg, R. S. 2019. Kirchhoff's Law can be Exact. arXiv preprint available at https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.13574.
2. Eisenberg, B., N. Gold, Z. Song, and H. Huang. 2018. What Current Flows Through a Resistor? arXiv preprint arXiv:1805.04814.

Comment: Is there a similar extension to KVL ?

Comment: @AJN Regarding KVL, it is exact when expressed in the proper form and inductive emf is properly defined. I will find a link for you.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. any energy the charge gains when traveling once around a loop is then balanced by placing the necessary induced EMF in the loop ?

Comment: @AJN KCL is a _node_ law, not a loop law. It says that if you enclose some volume, say a solder blob, by a surface, the total current into that volume (where current "into" can be negative, i.e. out of) is 0. Or, using schematics, the total current into a node (where current "into" can be negative) is 0. KVL is a _loop_ law, and requires one to pick a loop to analyse. [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/561968/268467) is an answer I gave regarding the use of KVL.

Comment: @AJN [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/631405/290970) is another answer which may help to clarify KVL.